# null is getting updated while calling function from stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update all price column when there is split in share.
to calculate price i have written function which works fine when I callfunction  from command prompt. But when I call function from inside cursor to update all the row its updating the row with null;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE updateshareprice(in p_isin varchar(50),in p_date date)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE v_cisin varchar(50);
        DECLARE v_nisin varchar(50);
        DECLARE v_activitydate date;
        DEClARE v_split varchar(20);
        DEClARE v_PREV_CLOSE float(10,4);
        DEClARE v_OPEN_PRICE float(10,4);
        DEClARE v_HIGH_PRICE float(10,4);
        DEClARE v_LOW_PRICE float(10,4);
        DEClARE v_LAST_PRICE float(10,4);
        DEClARE v_AVG_PRICE float(10,4);
        DEClARE v_CLOSE_PRICE float(10,4);          
        DEClARE v_symbol varchar(20);
        DEClARE v_date date;    

        DEClARE updateprice_cursor CURSOR FOR
        select date1,isin,symbol,PREV_CLOSE,OPEN_PRICE,HIGH_PRICE,LOW_PRICE,LAST_PRICE,AVG_PRICE,CLOSE_PRICE
        from nse_backup 
        where isin = p_isin
        and date1 < p_date
        order by date1 desc;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

        select split
        INTO @v_split
        from companysharehistory  
        where isin = p_isin
        and activitydate=p_date
        order by activitydate desc LIMIT 1; 

        OPEN updateprice_cursor;
        get_info: LOOP

            FETCH updateprice_cursor 
            INTO v_date,v_nisin,v_symbol,v_PREV_CLOSE,
            v_OPEN_PRICE,v_HIGH_PRICE,v_LOW_PRICE,v_LAST_PRICE,v_AVG_PRICE,v_CLOSE_PRICE;           
            IF v_finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE get_info;
            END IF;
            update nse_backup set 
            PREV_CLOSE=adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(v_PREV_CLOSE,v_split),
            OPEN_PRICE=adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(v_OPEN_PRICE,v_split), 
            HIGH_PRICE=adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(v_HIGH_PRICE,v_split),
            LOW_PRICE=adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(v_LOW_PRICE,v_split), 
            LAST_PRICE=adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(v_LAST_PRICE,v_split),
            AVG_PRICE=adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(v_AVG_PRICE,v_split), 
            CLOSE_PRICE=adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(v_CLOSE_PRICE,v_split)
            where isin = p_isin
            and date1 = v_date;
            END LOOP get_info;
            CLOSE updateprice_cursor;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Function which I am calling to return price, it works properly from command prompt , can someone guide me where I am doing mistake

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION adjustSharePriceBeforeActivity(price float, ratio varchar(20)) RETURNS float(10,4)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare firstratio  INT unsigned;    
    declare secondratio int unsigned;
    declare priceAfterafterchange float(10,4); 
    set secondratio  = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ratio,':',-1) AS UNSIGNED);
    set  firstratio = CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ratio,':',1) AS UNSIGNED) ;  
    set priceAfterafterchange = price/(firstratio/secondratio);

 RETURN (priceAfterafterchange);
END;
 $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You haven't coded for failure. What if select split
        INTO @v_split
        from companysharehistory   returns nothing?

Comment: Thanks it got resolved , pls ignore